# Producer and Consumer Problem waiting threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable, unique-lock

I tried to code Producer and Consumer Problem but after producing up to a certain value -(val) produce thread ends. but the consumer thread's condition variable waiting for notification but there is no thread to notify so my program does not end. What changes should I made?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
mutex m;
vector<int>buffer;
condition_variable cv;
void producer(int val){
    while(val){
        std::unique_lock<mutex>lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock, []{ return buffer.size()<50; });
        buffer.push_back(val--);
        cout<<"Produced : "<<buffer.back()<<endl;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
      }
}
void consumer(){
    while(1){
        std::unique_lock<mutex>lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock, []{return buffer.size() > 0 ; });
        cout<<"Consumed : "<<buffer.back()<<endl;
        buffer.pop_back();
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int attempt=1;
     thread t1(producer,30);
    thread t2(consumer);
  
    t1.join();
     t2.join();
 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: use another condition variable to notify the producer that the consumer is gone

Comment: The producer will get over first when it reaches the Limit(Loop ends) but the consumer will be waiting for the notification.

Comment: Add a Boolean flag which is set when the producer ends and can be checked by the consumer to stop waiting

Answer (score 1):

You need to have another variable which will indicate that your producer will produce no more so your consumer will know that

- it doesn't need to wait for the producer anymore.
- if it consumed the latest item it should stop the loop.

So the minimum modification of your code might look as follows:

```
using namespace std;
mutex m;
vector<int>buffer;
condition_variable cv;
bool producerExhausted = false;
void producer(int val){
    while(val){
        std::unique_lock<mutex>lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock, []{ return buffer.size()<50; });
        buffer.push_back(val--);
        cout<<"Produced : "<<buffer.back()<<endl;
        producerExhausted = val == 0;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}
void consumer(){
    while(1){
        std::unique_lock<mutex>lock(m);
        if(!producerExhausted)
            cv.wait(lock, []{return buffer.size() > 0 ; });
        cout<<"Consumed : "<<buffer.back()<<endl;
        buffer.pop_back();
        if(producerExhausted && buffer.empty())
            break;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Comment: its simpler to `producerExhausted = true;` after the loop. In your code the condition `val == 0` is present twice, but no matter what the condition the producer can notify the consumer when its loop finished

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number no, you can't set it after the loop. It should be set inside the mutex, otherwise that variable is useless.

Comment: oh right, one could use a different mutex, or `std::atomic`. Its additional cost, but that cost is only once and only when producer and consumer are finsihed anyhow

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it would be an additional cost per iteration on `consumer` not once on `producer`, also it would require adding another notification after the loop ended. Yes, it is also a possible solution but I don't like it more than what I did.

Comment: its a minor. I am only worried about `while(val)` and `producerExhausted = val == 0;` which could be done in one place. I didnt consider the issues you mention. Perhaps I'd use a `auto produce_more = [&]() { return val != 0; };` and call that in both places, just to have the stop condition only once. But yeah your code is fine as is